# Ignore carriage returns in scanf before data.... to keep layout of console based graphics with conio.h

Tags: c++, c, console, console-application, scanf

I have the misfortune of having use conio.h in vc++ 6 for a college assignment,

My problem is that my graphic setup is in the center of the screen...

e.g.

```
gotoxy( getcols()/2, getrows()/2);
printf("Enter something");
scanf( "%d", &something );
```

now if someone accidentally hits enter before they enter the "something", then the cursor gets reset to the left of the screen on the next line.

Iv tried flushing the keyboard and bios buffers with  fflush(stdin) and getchar(), which like I expected didn't work!

Any help/ideas would be appreciated,
Thanks,
V

Comment: FYI, you can only flush output buffers.  There is no notion of flushing an input buffer.

Comment: How do you explain this then? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/43993

Comment: There's the POSIX standard, which most C implementations try to adhere to, and then there's Microsoft, who ignore standards and cause compatibility headaches for everyone. Ironically, as the support doc indicates, MS' fflush() doesn't even work as one would expect ;)

Comment: I suspected something like tha, had to ask though.. thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @volting: I quit trying to explain Microsoft's products years ago.  From what I read in that document, it's a mis-use of the term "flush" and is simply reading in and discarding all characters from the input buffer.  "Flush" traditionally refers to ensuring that all data that you placed in a buffer has been sent out over the transmission medium.  Since you didn't place the input data into the buffer, you can't flush it.  Plus, it is already at its destination so if you "flushed" it, where would it go?

Comment: Ya I know.. it doesn't make any sense, don't really know why I referenced microshaft. I seem to have to flush the keyboard buffer with getchar() frequently when using conio.h functions, I guess that's just a peculiarity of conio, maybe there is better way... but that is all that worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The road to success will involve doing what the assignment asks you to do :) In particular, you should use one or more functions from `conio.h` to read your input. `scanf()` is *not* a conio.h function.

Because <s>I'm lazy</s> this is a homework question, I won't write the code for you.

One possibility would be to use `cscanf()` rather than `scanf()`. But this *may* (I don't know) echo input characters, which would include that accidental <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and not solve your problem.

If this is the case, my strategy would be to write a loop to gather characters entered from the keyboard, using the non-echoing `getch()` function. You can ignore newlines until you have at least one printable character, and then accept characters (and store them in a character array or whatever) until you get a newline. Since input characters won't be echoed, I think the cursor will not move.

You can then scan the input characters from your input buffer using `sscanf()`. You'll want to count input characters to make sure your user doesn't overflow your buffer. Also, probably some error handling in case of bad data.

**EDIT:** Something I forgot to mention: Your last input character in the buffer should be followed by a zero character ( `'\0'` ) so `sscanf()` will terminate properly. It's possible for your buffer to be full of zeros by default, but putting one in there intentionally (e.g. when you hit your final newline) will make your code more correct and robust.

Comment: Thanks I'm capable of writing my own code... just needed a little guidance, the conio.h functions can be a little quirky... I've used most of them... I tried ccscanf earlier but it didn't make a difference... will go with the strategy that you and bta suggested, seems the most logical approach, Thanks

Comment: What should be very simple is proving to be a pain... I seem to be back at square... basically  getch() would work fine if the input was characters, but I need integers... any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you need to read my suggestion more carefully. Once you have all your characters in a buffer, you use sscanf() to convert them to an integer.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! And sorry I forgot to mention you need to terminate your buffer with a trailing 0 (see edit).

Answer (score 3):

Try reading the user's input one character at a time.  If a leading carriage return is detected, ignore the character and run your `gotoxy( getcols()/2, (getrows()/2)+1)` code again to re-place the cursor at the appropriate location (adding one row to avoid writing over the previously-output message).

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work, Im sure I tryed something like this earlier though using getchar() which didnt work as Im trying to read integers, I think I strayed off in another direction then...